# Add HTTP Responsive Headers to homepage of WHMCS

Tags: php, whmcs, smarty3

I am trying to add/overwrite the HTTP Responsive Headers to the WHMCS public homepage.
Using PHP they should look like this:

```
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=10800, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
```

However, in smarty 3+ the use of php tags is no longer supported.

I have tried the following on the header.tpl file but failed:

```
{if $templatefile == 'homepage'}
  header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
  header("Pragma: cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
{/if}
```

How would I add these headers to the header.tpl file so they are read as PHP?
Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you calling them "Responsive Headers"?

Comment: Can you use `{php}`? https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl

Comment: smarty3 no longer supports the php tag. It cannot be embedded like that anymore.

Comment: What about with SmartyBC? https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl

Comment: Important question - why are you wanting to do this?  Is WHMCS not sending these headers, or is it sending them wrongly?

Comment: You can use a `hook` to add these headers depending on the `template` /`filename`. More specifically, you can use `ClientAreaHeadOutput`. See details: https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/output/#clientareaheadoutput

Comment: @M.HaseebAkhtar this is what I was going to suggest. Perhaps you should add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments, you can do this by using `ClientAreaHeadOutput` hook, like:

```
add_hook('ClientAreaHeadOutput', 1, function ($vars) {
    // Check if the current file name is index aka home
    if ($vars['filename'] == 'index') {
        header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=10800, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        header("Pragma: cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    }
});
```

You can also use `App::getCurrentFilename()` instead of `$vars['filename']` to get current file name.